# How to write Redux selectors that are both reusable and modular?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I am new to Redux and trying to figure out how to take full advantage of it.

When writing a selector for a module of the application, what part of the state tree should be passed to the selector so that the selector is both reusable and modular?

For example, given the code below, what is a good way to write `selectModuleItemsById` with a state shape similar to `stateShapeExample`?

```js
let stateShapeExample = {
    module: {
        items: {
            firstItemId: {...},
            secondItemId: {...},
            ...
        }
    }
}

const selectModuleRoot = (state) => state.module;

// First Option: starts from the module root
const selectModuleItemById = (state, id) => state.items[id];

// Second Option: starts from the global root
const selectModuleItemById = (state, id) => state.module.items[id];

// Something Else: ???
const selectItemById = (state, id) => state[id];
```

Comment: if your selectors refer to state's global root it would need more work to do once you decide decompose subtree into few or move some data to different state's branch

Comment: @skyboyer It would also be earier to use them from other parts of the applicaiton.  Since you would only need the one function to access the data you are looking for, you would not need to know the sequence of other selectors to call to get the state to pass in to the selector you need.  Changes to the state shape could change that sequence of selectors.  Then, there is no advantage to using selectors in the first place.  This is especially true if the item you are looking for is nested deeply in the state tree.

Comment: no, having `export const selectItemById = (globalState, id) => selectModuleRoot(globalState)[id]` you will not need to know sequence

Comment: @skyboyer But then `selectItemById` cannot be used to select other types of items by their id, so its reusability has been reduced.  There would also be problems if there were multiple instances of the module in the state tree.

Comment: Maybe you're after something like this `getEntityByIdentity(state, {id: 'abc123', type: 'module'})`. Also, you should avoid having copies of the same data in state; store id references instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that it's pretty tricky.

The best writeup on this that I've seen is Randy Coulman's series of posts on modularizing selectors:

- [Encapsulating the Redux State Tree](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/09/13/encapsulating-the-redux-state-tree/)
- [Redux Reducer/Selector Asymmetry](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/09/20/redux-reducer-selector-asymmetry/)
- [Modular Reducers and Selectors](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/09/27/modular-reducers-and-selectors/)
- [Solving Circular Dependencies in Modular Redux](http://randycoulman.com/blog/2018/06/12/solving-circular-dependencies-in-modular-redux/)

The general summary of that seems to be letting "module reducers" write selectors that know how to pick pieces of data out of their own state, then "globalizing" them at the app level based on where that module/slice is mounted in the state tree.  However, since the module probably needs to use the selectors itself, you may have to move the registration / setup process into a separate file to avoid a circular dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

Selectors, by definition, take in the entire state and return a portion of the state. Anything else is basically just a data utility function.

I use [ramda](https://ramdajs.com) lenses to manage this kind of thing.

Consider a directory structure like this:

```
store
  module
    data.js
    selectors.js
    reducers.js
    actions.js
```

`data.js` would export the initial state (in this case, just the initial state for `modules`) and ramda lenses that describe where pieces of state are.

```
import { lensPath } from 'ramda'

export default {
    items: {
        firstItemId: {...},
        secondItemId: {...},
        ...
    }
}

export const itemsLens = lensPath(['module', 'items'])
export const makeItemLens = id => lensPath(['module', 'items', id])
```

Then, in `selectors.js` you import the lenses to select the data from the entire state tree.

```
import {view} from 'ramda'
import {itemsLens, makeItemLens} from './data.js'

export const selectModuleItems = state => view(itemsLens, state)
export const selectModuleItemById = (state, id) => view(makeItemLens(id), state)
```

This strategy has a few benefits:

1. Using ramda's `lensPath` with `view` enables you to do deep property lookups without risking, `Cannot read propery firstItemId of undefined` errors. Other libraries have equivalent functions if ramda aint your thing (lodash, immutable.js, etc).
2. Having the lenses alongside your initial state adds a lot of clarity for other developers.
3. Abstracting object paths to lenses makes it a bit easier to restructure your state tree, if needed.

The downside is that it's a bunch of extra boilerplate code, but there's value in being explicit and avoiding magical code IMO.

Having said all that, you should also check out [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) for more advanced selector strategies (something I have yet to play with extensively).

Comment: It seems like the fact that selectors take the "entire" state man that they just can't be modular with pure Redux.  Would you say that is right?

Comment: What are you trying to modularize? Maybe this is what you're after: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#composing-selectors